# Special indent text next to image

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, styles

I'd like to generate some specific style where on the left side there is an image (icon) and next to the icon theres some kind of description (plain text).

So this is what I got so far:

```css
.elem {
  margin-left: 7%; 
  position: relative; 
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.img {
  width: 5%; 
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem">
   <img class="img" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/172871-200.png"/>
   <span class="text">
     (1) This is a example text
   </span>
</div>

<br>

<div class="elem">
   <img class="img" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/172871-200.png"/>
   <span class="text">
     (2) <b>This is a LONG example text, because this is a LONG example text while it's a LONG example text also this is a LONG example text, also because this is a LONG example text while all is a LONG example text</b>
   </span>
</div>
<br>

<div class="elem">
   <img class="img" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/172871-200.png"/>
   <span class="text">
     (3) This is a example text
   </span>
</div>
```

As you can see it's working quite fine but the `second elem (div)` with the long text is generating a line break what causes my text to float to the left.  But I want the lines to indent like the fist word in the sentence did. Have a look at the this:

[image: img]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try flex like this:

```css
.elem {
  margin-left: 7%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  padding-top:5px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.img {
  width: 30px;
  margin-top:-5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem">
  <img class="img" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/172871-200.png" >
   (1)
  <span class="text">
     This is a example text
   </span>
</div>

<div class="elem">
  <img class="img" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/172871-200.png" >
  (2)
  <span class="text">
      <b>This is a LONG example text, because this is a LONG example text while it's a LONG example text also this is a LONG example text, also because this is a LONG example text while all is a LONG example text</b>
   </span>
</div>

<div class="elem">
  <img class="img" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/172871-200.png" >
  (3)
  <span class="text">
      This is a example text
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a much lighter markup with this

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li>span {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

li:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  min-width: 32px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-image: url(https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/172871-200.png);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>(1)</span> This is a example text</li>
  <li><span>(2)</span> This is a LONG example text, because this is a LONG example text while it's a LONG example text also this is a LONG example text, also because this is a LONG example text while all is a LONG example text</li>
  <li><span>(3)</span> This is a example text</li>
</ul>
```

It is simple as that if need the same icon for every row but if you need different icon for some row you can target that row with `li:nth-child(n)` or assign it some class and just specify a `background-image: url()`

And if you want to align an icon to the center of the first row you can do this little trick:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

li>span {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

li:before {
  margin-top: -5px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  min-width: 32px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-image: url(https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/172871-200.png);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>(1)</span> This is a example text</li>
  <li><span>(2)</span> This is a LONG example text, because this is a LONG example text while it's a LONG example text also this is a LONG example text, also because this is a LONG example text while all is a LONG example text</li>
  <li><span>(3)</span> This is a example text</li>
</ul>
```